# Drag and Drop implementation on blender models

Tags: blend4web, webgl

Can drag and drop be implemented on the blender models via web design. As I am trying to make a web app that allows to drop and drop different car parts on a blender car model..

Comment: There's not enough information in the question background to allow me to form an opinion. For example, what platform (platform here meaning device + OS) do you intend your web app to run on? What design constraints are you planning to use? For example, it might be more possible to implement drag and drop on a car designed for minecraft, than for another set of design criteria, such as faithfulness to real world parameters. In other words, it would not be likely easy to mount a Corvette door on to a Shelby Mustang.

Comment: Well i am trying to, in short create a website which kinda runs on webGl compatible browsers.. platform intended is PC's laptops etc.. And I want to consider real world parameters while doing the drag and drop on the cars..

Comment: You definitely can implement drag-and-drop with Blend4Web. This will require some JavaScript coding though. Please ask on the B4W forums for more details.